# Spark stream job writing to Hdfs in a Json format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, stream, hdfs

I have made a spark streaming job, that polls massages from Kafka and stores it in a json format to Hdfs. Got an example from here : https://github.com/sryza/simplesparkavroapp/blob/specifics/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkavro/SparkSpecificAvroWriter.scala

There is another job that creates a hive table based on a avro with the following properties - AvroContainerInputFormat/ AvroConrainerOutputFormat. 
Now I’m facing a problem that produced json file is not visualized querying hive table. 
Seems that input/ output formats are different
Did someone had the similar problem ?

Comment: If you used `AvroContainerInputFormat`, then the table cannot have JSON files...

Comment: And fwiw, I would suggest trying out this rather than writing/copying Spark code https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs

Comment: @cricket_007, in fact used Kafka Connect before, but had continue problem with Load Balancing. thats why we are trying to use custom component.

Comment: Hmm. You could try asking a separate post, but Connect balances between itself of the same group. If you want to front all the servers themselves with another load balancer, then there's a `listeners` or `advertised.port` setting for that